# Regarding the Plackett-Burman screening design

Tags: experiment-design

I am starting to implement screening designs in my optimization work. The one I am most familiar with is the Plackett-Burman design, so I am starting there. I have written my own scripts in MATLAB but I am trying to reference them with minitab.

MATLAB suggests that users uses the hadamard command to generate a hadamard matrix for the desired number of factors. For instance, the call hadamard(8) produces an 8 by 8 hadamard matrix, where the second to last columns form the Plackett-Burman design. However, minitab only allows the user a few set number of runs: 12, 20, and so on (8 isn't an option). Is there something inherent to the Plackett-Burman design I am missing?

Second - one oft cited metric I have run into is that the effect of each factor [can be calculated according to](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlehtml/2013/ay/c3ay90020g)

$$
\text{Effect} = \frac{2 \left[\sum (y+) - \sum(y-)  \right]}{N}
$$

where $y(+)$ is the response of an experiment at the high leve, $y(-)$ the response at the low level, and $N$ the number of experiments. I have performed this calculation in MATLAB and I get the same result as Minitab produces. However, I am a bit curious where this equation derive from ? what I am more concerned about is the following: from what I can tell, minitab compares these effects to the $t$-value at the specified number of DOF. However, I don't see how these two are comparable? Why should the significance of an "effect" be equivalent to a $t$-value?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not easy to generate Plackett-Burman designs/Hadamard matrices in full generality, so software tends to have a few pre-calculated ones and perhaps the ability to expand them into families of larger matrices.

It's easy to calculate Hadamard matrices of order $n=2^k(p+1)$, where $p$ is prime and $p+1$ is a multiple of 4.  Also, given matrices of orders $m$ and $n$ it is easy to make one of order $2n$ or $mn$, so if you store a few examples you can make bigger ones.  (There are other families of Hadamard matrices, eg of order $n=2^k(p^r+1)$ for $r>1$, but these are less easy to generate).

[Matlab](https://la.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hadamard.html) says it provides Hadamard matrices of order $n$ where $n$, $n/12$ or $n/20$ is a power of 2. (Matlab is thinking of these as Hadamard matrices)

Minitab has Plackett-Burman designs for 12-48 levels (except for $n=16$). The documentation says 8 and 16 are left out because there are factorial designs with better resolution (Minitab is clearly thinking of these as designs, not as matrices with other potential uses)

The `survey` package for R has a `hadamard` function that gives more possible values.